# Android BaseAdapter's getCount() getView()

Tags: android, listview, gridview, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdapter with 3 kind of layout which is used to put JSONObject to my ListView. The adapter getCount() returns correct number of items that should be displayed on the ListView, but it only display the first one.

I tried to find another response to this problem here, but i've found none.

This is my code:

```
public class PerfilInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_TITULO = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_DESCRICAO = 1;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_KEY_VALUE = 2;

    private JSONArray list;
    private Activity activity;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;

    public PerfilInfoAdapter(Activity activity, JSONArray list) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    protected class ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitulo;
        TextView textViewDescricao;
        TextView textViewKey;
        TextView textViewValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("PerfilInfoAdapter", "Number of items in array: " + Integer.toString(this.list.length()));
        return this.list.length();
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = this.list.getJSONObject(position);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        int retorno = -1;

        JSONObject json = null;

        try {
            json = this.list.getJSONObject(position);

            if (json.getString("key").equals("Titulo")) {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_TITULO;
            } else if (json.getString("key").equals("Descrição")
                    || json.getString("key").equals("Sou")) {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_DESCRICAO;
            } else {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_KEY_VALUE;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View container, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + container);

        this.viewHolder = null;

        int type = this.getItemViewType(position);

        if (container == null) {
            this.viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            switch (type) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TITULO:
                container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.perfil_info_full_titulo, viewGroup, false);

                this.viewHolder.textViewTitulo = (TextView) container
                        .findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_full_textViewTitulo);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_DESCRICAO:
                container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.perfil_info_full_descricao, viewGroup, false);

                this.viewHolder.textViewDescricao = (TextView) container
                        .findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_full_textVewDescricao);
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_KEY_VALUE:
                container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.perfil_info_list, viewGroup, false);

                this.viewHolder.textViewKey = (TextView) container
                        .findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_full_chave_valor_textFieldChave);
                this.viewHolder.textViewValue = (TextView) container
                        .findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_full_chave_valor_textFieldValor);
                break;
            }

            container.setTag(this.viewHolder);

        } else {
            this.viewHolder = (ViewHolder)container.getTag();
        }

        try {
            JSONObject json = this.list.getJSONObject(position);

            switch (type) {
            case VIEW_TYPE_TITULO:
                this.viewHolder.textViewTitulo.setText(json.getString("value"));
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_DESCRICAO:
                this.viewHolder.textViewDescricao.setText(json
                        .getString("value"));
                break;
            case VIEW_TYPE_KEY_VALUE:
                this.viewHolder.textViewKey.setText(json.getString("key"));
                this.viewHolder.textViewValue.setText(json.getString("value"));
                break;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return container;
    }

}
```

This is what my log returns:

> 10-26 09:42:30.568: D/PerfilInfoAdapter(17228): Number of items in
>   array: 11

Another important information is that my ListView is inside another GridView, which has 4 different kinds of views, the gridView is working perfectly, but not the ListView.

```
public class PerfilAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<JSONObject> jsonList;
    private Activity activity;
    private PerfilHelper helper;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private boolean exibirFull;

    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_FOTO_PRINCIPAL = 0;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_INFO = 1;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_INFO_LIST = 2;
    public static final int VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA = 3;

    public PerfilAdapter(Activity activity, List<JSONObject> json, PerfilHelper helper) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.helper = helper;
        this.jsonList = json;
        this.exibirFull = true;

        if (!ImageLoader.getInstance().isInited()) {
            ImageLoader.getInstance().init(new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this.activity).build());
        }
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    public void exibirFull(boolean exibir) {
        this.exibirFull = exibir;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.jsonList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return this.jsonList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        int retorno = -1;

        if (this.jsonList.get(0).has("foto")) {
            if (position == 0) {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_FOTO_PRINCIPAL;
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                retorno =  VIEW_TYPE_INFO;
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                if (this.exibirFull) {
                    retorno =  VIEW_TYPE_INFO_LIST;
                }
                else {
                    retorno = VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA;
                }
            }
            else {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (position == 0) {
                retorno =  VIEW_TYPE_INFO;
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                if (this.exibirFull) {
                    retorno =  VIEW_TYPE_INFO_LIST;
                }
                else {
                    retorno = VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA;
                }
            }
            else {
                retorno = VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA;
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    public void updateJsonPerfil(List<JSONObject> json) {
        this.jsonList = json;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View container, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        this.viewHolder = null;

        int type = this.getItemViewType(i);

        if (container == null) {
            this.viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            switch (type) {
                case VIEW_TYPE_FOTO_PRINCIPAL:
                    container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.perfil_foto, viewGroup, false);

                    this.viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) container.findViewById(R.id.perfil_foto_imageView);
                    break;
                case VIEW_TYPE_INFO:
                    container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.perfil_info, viewGroup, false);

                    this.viewHolder.textViewApelido = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_apelido);
                    this.viewHolder.textViewCidade = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_textVewCidade);
                    this.viewHolder.textViewDistancia = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_textViewDistancia);
                    break;
                case VIEW_TYPE_INFO_LIST:
                    container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.perfil_info_list, viewGroup, false);

                    this.viewHolder.listViewInfo = (ListView) container.findViewById(R.id.perfil_info_list_listView);               
                    break;
                case VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA:
                    container = this.activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.perfil_info, viewGroup, false);
                    break;
            }

            container.setTag(this.viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            this.viewHolder = (ViewHolder)container.getTag();
        }

        if (this.jsonList.size() > 0) {
            JSONObject json = this.jsonList.get(i);

            try {
                if (type == VIEW_TYPE_FOTO_PRINCIPAL) {
                    JSONObject foto = json.getJSONObject("foto");
                    this.imageLoader.displayImage(foto.getString("full"), this.viewHolder.imageView);
                }
                else if (type == VIEW_TYPE_INFO) {
                    JSONObject perfil = json.getJSONObject("perfil");
                    this.viewHolder.textViewApelido.setText(perfil.getString("apelido"));
                    this.viewHolder.textViewCidade.setText(perfil.getString("cidade"));
                    this.viewHolder.textViewDistancia.setText(perfil.getString("distancia"));
                }
                else if (type == VIEW_TYPE_INFO_LIST) {

                    // This is where i use the second ListView
                    this.viewHolder.listViewInfo.setAdapter(new PerfilInfoAdapter(this.activity, json.getJSONArray("info")));

                }
                else {
                    Log.d("PerfilAdapter", "Populando: VIEW_TYPE_GALERIA");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return container;
    }

    protected class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;

        TextView textViewApelido;
        TextView textViewCidade;
        TextView textViewDistancia;

        ListView listViewInfo;
    }

}
```

I have tried changing the ListView to a GridView, but the problem is with the adapter.

Can anybody help me? I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem: Trying to combine a `ListView` and a `GridView`. Never ever **ever** put one within the other.  You'll have all sorts of problems...as you are noticing.  The first big problem is scrolling.  Android does not like it when a scrollable view is embedded within another and both scroll the **same** direction. [Comical sketch](https://plus.google.com/+AdamWPowell/posts/T5AgJ7jiK88) from Android employee about this.  Doing so is only viable when one scrolls horizontally and the other vertically.

Your next big problem, embedding a `ListAdapter` within another `ListAdapter`. You have to remember, that the `getView()` method can be invoked 3-4 times per position.  When you embed another adapter for each position which itself will be invoked 3-4 times per it's own position...holy performance hit! This has bad idea written all over it.

A concern I see is your `JSONArray`/`List` referencing. The `PerfilInfoAdapter` maintains the same reference to the `JSONArray` used to instantiate it...which is the same data referenced by the `PerfilAdapter` `List`. Further the `PerfilAdapter` maintains the same list referenced by whomever is using it.  This sets up a dangerous chain of references that can cause issues when modifying if you are not careful. Ideally, each adapter should maintain the same data in its on `List` or `JSONArray` instance.

To sum up, the answer is to change your design choice. There are other ways to display data other then needing vertical scrolling within vertical scrolling. If the `ListView` doesn't need scrolling use a `LinearLayout`. If the `GridView` doesn't need scrolling use a `TableLayout` or `GridLayout`. Or just completely change the UX by coming up with a different UI.

As a side note, if you need a full fledged JSONArray adapter check out [Advanced-Adapters](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters). The JSONAdapter is releasing within a week or so and can be found on the `Redesign` branch. Its code complete, just the demo app that's holding up the release.

Comment: Is it possible to use a GridView with different item width?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking. A `GridView` columns must all be of equal width.

Answer (score 0):

How about implement `getItem` correctly (not return null)?

or I prefer

1. make POJO class and convert JSON into it. (like using `GSON`)
2. extends `ArrayAdapter` instead of `BaseAdapter` so that u don't have to implements all abstract methods.

Comment: The getItem is not the problem. I've change it, just to make sure, but the problem persists.